# Sorting of HTML Rows based on keywords using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to sort the HTML Table with specific keywords. e.g. Sorting "AX", "BY", "CZ", "DQ" using jQuery.
My table contains multiple rows with one of cells containing  above values

```
 <table>
 <tr><td>Test1</td><td>BY</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test2</td><td>AX</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test3</td><td>DQ</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test4</td><td>AX</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test5</td><td>DQ</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test6</td><td>CZ</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test7</td><td>CZ</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test8</td><td>AX</td></tr>
 </table>
```

Table should be re-arranged to following:

```
 <table>
 <tr><td>Test8</td><td>AX</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test2</td><td>AX</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test4</td><td>AX</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test1</td><td>BY</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test6</td><td>CZ</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test7</td><td>CZ</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test3</td><td>DQ</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Test5</td><td>DQ</td></tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+sort+table+based+on+values)?

Comment: Thankz But I'm done!!!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('TABLE > TBODY > TR > TD:nth-child(1)').each(function () {
    var cellText = $.trim($(this).text());
    var row = $(this).closest("TR");
    switch (cellText) {
        case AX:
            SetPriority(row, 0);
            break;
        case BY:
            SetPriority(row, 1);
            break;
        case CZ:
            SetPriority(row, 2);
            break;
        case DQ:
            SetPriority(row, 3);
            break;
        default:
            SetPriority(row, 4);
            break
    }
});

function SetPriority(row, priority) {
    row.attr("RowIndex", priority);
}

var $table = $('TABLE');
var rows = $table.find('tr').get();

rows.sort(function (a, b) {
    var keyA = $(a).attr('RowIndex');
    var keyB = $(b).attr('RowIndex');
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
});

$.each(rows, function (index, row) {
    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
});
```

Comment: The question was about ordering of table rows based on predefined string, which can't be evaluated using comparison operator.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sort` method:

```
$('table tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $('td:eq(1)', a).text() > $('td:eq(1)', b).text();
}).appendTo('tbody');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NrUCw/

Answer (score 2):

It would be wise to give your table an id:

```
<table id="mytable">
```

then you can sort the elements like you would sort a javascript array using a predicate function:

**Javascript**

```
var keywordWeights = { "AX": 0, "BY": 1, "CZ": 2, "DQ": 3 };

$(function() {
    $("#mytable tr").sort(function(a, b) {
        var tagA = $("td:nth-child(2)", a).html();
        var tagB = $("td:nth-child(2)", b).html();
        weightA = tagA in keywordWeights ? keywordWeights[tagA] : Number.MAX_VALUE;
        weightB = tagB in keywordWeights ? keywordWeights[tagB] : Number.MAX_VALUE;
        return weightA - weightB;
    }).appendTo("tbody");
});
```

[See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZYeq/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow users to sort, filter etc maybe you should consider using data tables it will save you a lot of time: http://www.datatables.net/ :)